# Why is stat = "identity" necessary in geom_bar in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008219/how-to-plot-dates-as-dates-not-numbers-or-character-on-x-axis-of-ggplot) question we see a simple `geom_line` in the answer.

```
library(dplyr)
BactData %>% filter(year(Date) == 2017) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Svartediket_CB )) + geom_line()
```

If we change `geom_line` to `geom_bar` we may expect to see a bar plot, but instead

> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

But it works if we add `stat = "identity"`, like so

```
library(dplyr)
BactData %>% filter(year(Date) == 2017) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Svartediket_CB )) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Why doesn't `geom_bar` work without `stat = "identity"` - i.e. what is the purpose of `stat = "identity"`?

Comment: Have you read through the docs? "geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col() instead. geom_bar() uses stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases at each x position. geom_col() uses stat_identity(): it leaves the data as is." `geom_bar` was added as an alternative the would do that counting for you.

Comment: @camille so `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` and `geom_col()` do exactly the same thing?

Comment: As far as I've ever seen, yes. `geom_bar` is a version that expects to do some calculation; `stat_identity` is one possible calculation where y-values are placed at their actual values

Answer (score 48):

There are two layers that are closely related: `geom_bar()` and `geom_col()`. The key difference is how they aggregate the data by default.

For `geom_bar()`, the default behavior is to count the rows for each *x* value. It doesn't expect a *y*-value, since it's going to count that up itself -- in fact, it will flag a warning if you give it one, since it thinks you're confused. How aggregation is to be performed is specified as an argument to `geom_bar()`, which is `stat = "count"` for the default value.

If you explicitly say `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar()`, you're telling `ggplot2` to skip the aggregation and that you'll provide the *y* values. This mirrors the natural behavior of `geom_col()` below.

In the case of `geom_col()`, it won't try to aggregate the data by default. From the docs, "`geom_col()` uses `stat_identity()`: it leaves the data as is". So, it expects you to already have the *y* values calculated and to use them directly. And `geom_col()` doesn't have an argument to change that behavior - it's always going to plot your *y* values that you provide, and you need to provide them.

If you have *y* values, you could use either syntax, but I find `geom_col()` more direct.

Comment: If you could provide some examples, that would be welcome.

Answer (score 7):

@Stevec.

I found the answer at [rdocumentation.org](https://rdocumentation.org).

See below what means **stat='identity'**:

> "The heights of the bars commonly represent one of two things: either a count of cases in each group, or the values in a column of the data frame. By default, geom_bar uses stat="bin". This makes the height of each bar equal to the number of cases in each group, and it is incompatible with mapping values to the y aesthetic. If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use stat="identity" and map a value to the y aesthetic."

Hope this was helpful.

Follow the link to documentation: [geom_bar documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/geom_bar#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20geom_bar%20uses%20stat,value%20to%20the%20y%20aesthetic.)

Answer (score 6):

By default `geom_bar()` uses `stat_count()` to plot the frequency of cases at each level of `x` (some grouping variable). By contrast, this can be overridden with `stat_identity()` by supplying the argument `stat = "identity"` to plot the value at each level of `x`. The reason being `geom_bar()` is intended to plot frequencies, otherwise a single value could be more efficiently represented by a single point.