# What exactly does stat=identity mean in geom_bar ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm working through someone else's work and having trouble understanding the purpose of this line of code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Group, y = Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", lwd = 1,  aes(fill = Group))
```

Here's an example of the data

```
   Group  Value
1    A      20
2    B      74
3    B      50
...
n    A      24
```

I think the purpose of the code used was to plot a bar graph summarising the value of group A and of group B. However I believe a bar is plotted for every element of group A and of group B, and all these bars overlap and only the maximum value of each group is shown.
Is this the case?
I think the aim was to plot a summary statistic, either the mean or median rather than plot all and only being able to see the maximum.

If this is not what is happening I'd appreciate any help in understanding what the use of stat='identity' means as reading the documentation hasn't helped me much.

Thank you

Comment: stat identity uses the values directly. The default stat counts the numbers of each value. Better to use `geom_col()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is stat = "identity" necessary in geom\_bar in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008974/why-is-stat-identity-necessary-in-geom-bar-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 4):

By default `geom_bar()` is similar to a discrete version of `geom_histogram()`. Without `stat = "identity"`, it performs a statistical transformation `stat_bin(Group)`, which counts the number of observations at each value of `Group`, then a variable `count` is generated and automatically mapped onto y-axis and represented by the height of bars. So it will be invalid to supply `aes(y)` without `stat = "identity"`, since a y variable is computed by `geom_bar()` instead of being specified by you. `stat = "identity"` is useful when you don't want the height of bars to be counts of your x variable, but some value column in your data, so `geom_bar()` will just do nothing and wait for you to supply a y variable.

If you want to plot a summary statistic for each `Group`, and that summary isn't count of observations, you will have to use `group_by(Group) + summarize(mean(value) / median(value))` before plotting. And then use `stat = identity` and `aes(x = Group, y = summary)`, with `summary` being the column you want to display

Comment: Yes I get this, but by using stat="identity" is it overlaying the bars of all the elements in group A? And therefore only the maximum value is shown? Thanks

Comment: There is also `position = "dodge"` in your code, so that bars at the same x position will dodge each other and be displayed side by side. Without this position adjustment all the elements from the same group will be overlap.