# Why does my bar chart have all frequencies at 1?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am working on bar chart made with `ggplot2`.

The table is the following:

```
general_status  size       Freq
 <fctr>         <fctr>     <dbl>
Active          Large      0.0023858634     
Failed          Large      0.0003226497     
Active          Medium     0.0137466194     
Failed          Medium     0.0033334651     
Active          Micro      0.5623731202     
Failed          Micro      0.3130003976     
Active          Small      0.0850353345     
Failed          Small      0.0198025500
```

To make the graph I used the code:

```
g <- ggplot(freqtable, aes(size))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=general_status), width = 0.5) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) +
  labs(title="Size distribution", y = "Frequence", x = "Company size") +
  facet_grid(~ general_status) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

My question is: How can I plot the right frequencies?
Where is the error in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is stat = "identity" necessary in geom\_bar in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008974/why-is-stat-identity-necessary-in-geom-bar-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geom_bar` doesn’t just plot data directly; it first *counts* events in your table (it computes a count statistic). Since each `general_status` event occurs exactly once (one row), all frequencies are 1.

Use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`, or pass `stat = 'identity'` to fix this: both of these will plot the specified value (you’ll need to specify `y = Freq` in the `aes`) instead of computing its own statistic.